# Permanently switching to zsh in a script, without being root and without being asked for the password

Tags: linux, shell, users, non-root-user

Is there any way to run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` without being root and without being asked for the password? I want to put it into a non-interactive script that isn't called by root.

Comment: I'm not prompted for a password when I do that, it just changes my shell and exits

Comment: @Michael What distro are you using? I'm in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Gentoo. sys-apps/shadow-4.1.4.3

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you get root to cooperate (e.g. by adding a custom `sudoers` rule)? It's rare to need to automate something over multiple accounts without being root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the permission to change your login shell, you can tell bash (I assume bash is your login shell) to replace itself with zsh. In your `~/.bash_login`, add this line:

```
exec /bin/zsh --login
```

Comment: Whoa, careful! With some distributions or desktop environments (I don't remember specific cases outright), if you do this, you'll find that you can't log in under X (because `/etc/?dm/Xsession` calls `bash --login`).

Comment: Gilles, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq01.html#l8

Comment: This seems to break all non interactive commands(scp, rsync).

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `chsh` requires a password (mine does), you will need to setup sudo with special permissions. You can configure it to allow access to any program without prompting for a password like this:

```
user   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/chsh
```

Where "user" is your username (or prefix with % for a group name). Make sure specify the full path to your `chsh`. This will not allow the user to run anything ELSE as root (including from a script) but it will allow that one binary to be run as root without a password, thus bypassing the user-password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, if you want to do this because you’re running a long script and don’t want it to hang in the middle to that question, you can ask for the password upfront and then execute `chsh` with `sudo` privileges, reading the password from `stdin`.

```
read -p 'What is your password?' sudo_password

# rest of the script here

sudo -S chsh -s '/bin/zsh' "${USER}" <<< "${sudo_password}"
```

`-S` causes `sudo` to read the password from `stdin`. Be aware of [possible security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250391/any-security-risks-with-sudo-password-from-standard-input-over-ssh) with this approach (I haven’t been able to reproduce that, though, and again, depending on your needs this might not be an issue).